# Extending InputStreamReader does not work correctly

Tags: java, io

I extend InputStreamReader this way

```java
public class AsteriskInputStreamReader extends InputStreamReader {
    boolean ast;
    AsteriskInputStreamReader(InputStream is) {
        super(is);
    }
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        ast = !ast;
        if (ast) return '*';
        return super.read();
    }
}
```

It has to add '*' symbol after every symbol it gets from the original `InputStream`.
But when I use it like this

```java
InputStreamReader in = new AsteriskInputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("text.txt"));
int c;
while((c = in.read()) != -1){
     System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

It works correctly with the *last line* in the file only.
The previous lines output as one '*' only without any text.
Why?

And the second problem.

When I create `BufferedInputStream` with it and try to get first line of the file

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
System.out.println(reader.readLine());
```

I get the first line of the file *without any* '*'.

What is the right way to get what I want: create wrapper for `InputStreamReader`, which will add asterisk symbol  after all symbols from the original input?

Comment: I can't reproduce your first issue. Can you show the input file?

Comment: @Sweeper, look at [screenshot](https://ibb.co/YBKZyXF), please. It's under IntelliJ IDEA and the answer below to filter '\r' helped me.

Comment: ah, line endings. I was on macOS so there wasn’t any \r in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first part appears to be that you are writing out carriage-return characters.  Try skipping them from the output by replacing the line `System.out.print((char)c);` with

```java
if (c != '\r') {
    System.out.print((char) c);
}
```

For the second part, you will also need to override the `InputStreamReader` method `read(char[] cbuf, int offset, int length)` in your `AsteriskInputStreamReader` class.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of subclassing [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), create a separate [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) that you can chain with other readers, so you can also apply it to readers that are not backed by [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

```java
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new AsteriskReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader(
                                      new FileInputStream("text.txt"))))) {
    // ...
}
```

<sup>*Formatted to emphasize the chain.*</sup>

The reason that it doesn't work with [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) is that it doesn't call the [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read--) method that you overwrote, it calls one of the overloads that takes a buffer ([`read(char[] cbuf)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read-char:A-), [`read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read-char:A-int-int-), or [`read(CharBuffer target)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read-java.nio.CharBuffer-)).

To implement a `Reader` that is to be chained, subclass [`FilterReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html).

```java
class AsteriskReader extends FilterReader {
    private boolean ast;
    private boolean astMarked;

    public AsteriskReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        // TODO Add handling of EOF
        ast = !ast;
        if (ast) return '*';
        return super.read();
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        // TODO Implement this, i.e. only read half number of characters from
        //      underlying reader, then inject '*' characters between all the
        //      chars actually read.
        //      Special handling for odd value of len.
        int charsRead = super.read(cbuf, off, len);
        return charsRead;
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        // TODO Fix this to handle odd value of n.
        long actualSkipped = super.skip(n / 2);
        return actualSkipped * 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void mark(int readAheadLimit) throws IOException {
        super.mark((readAheadLimit + 1) / 2); // Underlying reader only needs to remember half
        this.astMarked = this.ast;
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        super.reset();
        this.ast = this.astMarked;
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, @Andeas, thank you very much for FilterReader. int charsRead = super.read(cbuf, off, len); is so simple!